# There is something laying on the remote machine's keyboard. How can I disable the key?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, remote-desktop

I'm using [TeamViewer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigy4LE14TOAhVFMz4KHR02CGkQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.teamviewer.com%2Fen%2Fdownload%2Fwindows%2F&usg=AFQjCNGbzYnsIcUNIo79MBtjtztsVe7zjg&sig2=ZazMafVEcgBhPIn2gVjvKg&bvm=bv.127521224,d.cWw) to connect to a remote Ubuntu machine.
I think there might be something laying on the remote machine's keyboard.
Wherever I click,  it continuously types the letter `u`.

This makes using the terminal too difficult,  and holding in `u`,
prevents me from clicking on Desktop icons.

Is there a way I can disable the `u` button while the `u` is being held?

---

**progress 1:**
I can now run commands in the terminal, by quickly pasting them into teamviewer between hitting enter and having a `u` appear.

---

**progress 2:**
I managed to run `xev`.  This showed me that the key code for `u` was `0x75`.
I tried to run the following commands, but it did not disable it:

```
xmodmap -e '75 = NoSymbol'
```

gave a parse error

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 75='
```

executed without error, but did not solve the problem.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong keycode.  For `u`, the keycode was actually `30`.
Running the command:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 30 = 0x0000'
```

disabled the key on the remote machine.
This doesn't prevent me from typing `u` on my end.